# unable to run app on my iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios10, ios10.2

NOTE: I am using iPhone 6s for testing.

Error:

requires the following capabilities which are not supported by My iPhone:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description 
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Where as i have already added my keys in the pInfo.list

Please find the attached image.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you have under the "Required device capabilities" key in your Info.plist?

Comment: @rmaddy i have 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>Privacy - Camera Usage Description </string>
</plist>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
</plist>

Comment: Update your screenshot to show the 3 values under "Required device capabilities".

Comment: I have updated it. Please check. There was an unwanted key i removed  @rmaddy

Comment: Unrelated but you should provide better values for the "Privacy" messages. The user already knows your app requires access. Your message should explain why it needs access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have entered invalid "required device capabilities" values. Delete those invalid entries and your issue will go away.

See [Declaring the Required Device Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW10) for the valid list of values you might use.

Comment: It installed the app after i removed the keys. But while opening the app it says Untrusted developer . Your device management settings do not allow apps from developer "xx" on this phone. You can allow using these apps in settings. Where in Setings i can enable this? @rmaddy

Comment: @NewbieIOS rmaddy may or may not answer, but what you are now doing is "leeching". Your question was answered. If you have a new question, ask a new question!

Comment: I got the answer using this link.
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206143/ios-untrusted-developer-error-when-testing-app.

Comment: I am sorry about that @matt. But thanks for mentioning that.